# How to get Python list into Jinja2 and paste as Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, jinja2

I'm building a website using the Python Flask Framework which includes the Jinja2 templating engine. I now want to pass a simple list of strings from Flask to Jinja2 to be included in a Javascript in the website. Using the tips in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322060/1650012) I tried doing this as follows:

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    theList = ['A', 'B']
    return render_template('index.html', theList=json.dumps(theList))
```

and in the template its Javascript I do this:

```
var theList = {{ theList }};
```

But when I look into the source of the generate Javascript I see this:

```
var theList = [&#34;A&#34;, &#34;B&#34;];
```

I also tried `theList=map(json.dumps, theList))`, which results in the even weirder:

```
var theList = [&#39;&#34;A&#34;&#39;, &#39;&#34;B&#34;&#39;];
```

Does anybody know how I can properly pass a simple list through Jinja2 on to a Javascript array? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Use `listobj|tojson|safe`, no need to use `json.dumps()` here.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tip! Works like a charm. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.. :)

Comment: I can't because I closed your question as a duplicate already. :-)