# How to pass a list of strings from flask python main function to javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, mustache

I am building a web site using flask. In the app.py file, I calculated out some stats that are passed to the html page.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    values = [10, 11, 7, 15, 19, 5, 7.5, 10.9]
    days= ["12/18/18","12/25/18","1/1/19","1/8/19","1/15/19","1/22/19","1/29/19","2/5/19"]

return render_template('index.html', days = days, values=values)
```

The javascript in the index.html is as follows

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart");
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: {{days}}
    datasets: {
      label: "All users",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(30,144,255, 0.31)",
      borderColor: "rgba(30,144,255, 0.7)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(30,144,255, 0.7)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(30,144,255, 0.7)",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      data: {{values}}
    }
  },
});
```

I tested two options in the javascript:

1. Not working (can't generate the chart plot)

   ```
   labels: {{days}}
   data: {{values}}
   ```
2. Working if I explicitly give list of strings

   ```
   labels: ["12/18/18","12/25/18","1/1/19","1/8/19","1/15/19","1/22/19","1/29/19","2/5/19"]
   data: {{values}}
   ```

It seems that passing the numeric arrays (values in this example) is fine but passing the list of strings will cause trouble.

Do you have any suggestions to address the issue?
Much appreciated!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15322060/2800058) might help.

Comment: yeah what they said, you need to put it in the template with the `{{data | safe}}` filter

Comment: Thanks! The 'safe' method solves the problem when I am hosting the app in my local windows pc! But it fails if I deploy it in the Ubuntu machine using Apache2.. Do you know what might be cause?

Comment: I added one more stuff that solved the problem: {{data | tojson |safe}}

Answer (score 0):

Put the jinja values in double quotes. That works. Write `"{{values}}"` instead of `{{values}}`.