# using charts in appengine with Jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-visualization

Can anybody provide an example of using Python appengine with Jinja2 templates to draw a chart created by code?

Assume there is a python list of two item lists/tuples:

```
table=[(1,1),(2,2),(3,4)]
```

and we want to pass that to a jinja2 template. Prefer to have the JavaScript in the body not in the head.

Wish Google devs had provided such an example in the docs, appengine is a most natural application for Google Charts.

Comment: I think I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321431/how-to-pass-a-list-from-python-by-jinja2-to-javascript

Comment: Are you asking how to draw the chart, or how to pass the data to the template?

Comment: how to pass the data. drawing the chart is well exemplified in the documentation.